# Fetching inputted form data in modal of different page

Tags: html, forms

I have created a register form inside a modal of index page , when user submit it, user gets directed to 2nd page which is confirmation through PHP.

If users gets an error it is necessary to go back to previous page and fill the whole form again, how can i save the values inputted by user recently and when he gets redirected to previous page he see the form but filled of his recent values

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="registermodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true"> x </span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h3 class="modal-title text-center" id="lineModalLabel"> Register </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <!-- content goes here -->
        <form action="confirmation.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div id="cfirstname" class="form-group" style="float:left;width:45%;">
            <label for="firstname"> First Name </label>
            <input oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter your first name')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First name" autocomplete="off">
          </div>
          <div id="clastname" class="form-group" style="float:right;width:45%;">
            <label for="lastname"> Last Name </label>
            <input oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter your last name')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name" autocomplete="off">
          </div>
          <div id="cemail" class="form-group" style="clear:both;">
            <label for="email"> Email </label>
            <input oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter your email name')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off">
          </div>
          <div id="ccategory" class="form-group" style="clear:both;">
            <label for="category"> Category </label>
            <input oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Category is Required')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required type="text" class="form-control" id="category" name="category" placeholder="Category" autocomplete="off"> <span class="help">Enter the category you are expert in </span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group ">
            <label for="Password"> Password </label>
            <input oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a password)" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required type="password" class="form-control" name="rpassword" id="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
            <span id="8char" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="color:#FF0004;"></span> 8 Characters Long<br>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group ">
            <label for="Password">Confirm Password </label>
            <input oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please confirm your password')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required type="password" class="form-control" name="rcpassword" id="cpassword" placeholder="Repeat Password" autocomplete="off">
            <span id="pwmatch" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="color:#FF0004;"></span> Passwords Match
          </div>
          <div id="cfblink" class="form-group">
            <label for="fblink"> Facebook profile link </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fblink" name="fblink" placeholder="Facebook Link" autocomplete="off">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ppic">Please upload an image of yourself</label>
            <input class="btn btn-default" required="required" type="file" name="file" id="file">
            <span id="cppic" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="color:#FF0004;"></span> Image uploaded
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="group button">
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" role="button">Close</button>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="submit" id="signup" name="signup" class="btn btn-default btn-hover-green" role="button"> Proceed </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i found answer myself just put the variable as value input tag

```
 <input oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter your first name')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First name" autocomplete="off" <?php echo 'value="'.$variable_name.'"'; ?> >
```